# Making two jquery animations work one after another

Tags: jquery, animation

I am using a callback function to execute a fadeIn animation after a slideUp. The animation can be seen here on clicking the down arrow:
https://rimildeyjsr.github.io/St.Anthony-Website/

There is a white background appearing between the two animations, which I suspect is due to the delay between both the animations. How to fix the animations so that as soon as the slideUp is over, the fadeIn kicks in, and the white background is avoided.

jQuery:

```
 $(".down-arrow").click(function() {
     $(".school-logo").fadeOut(200);
     $(".page-load-screen").slideUp(1000,"easeInOutBack",function(){
         $(".page-one-pic").fadeIn(500);
         $(".school-name").delay(500).fadeIn(500);
         $(".down-arrow-page-one").delay(1500).fadeIn().one(animationEnd, function(){
              carousel();
             });
         });
     });
```

Link to github repository: https://github.com/rimildeyjsr/St.Anthony-Website

Answer (score 0):

Change your fadeIn

```
$(".page-one-pic").fadeIn(500);
```

to

```
$(".page-one-pic").css({opacity: 0.05}).animate({opacity: 1},500);
```

Comment: there are a lot of images and animations on it, all dependent on each other. its difficult to put it all together in the fiddle

Comment: Fair point, But you are talking about an animation of blocks that happen to be images. How about making divs that match the size of the images. I reckon you need 2 divs - one for the starting image and one for the image that is meant to scroll and appear. An onclick on the first div to kick off the animation. That would be enough to feel our way through it.

Answer (score 0):

though you don't have any code snippet or jsfiddle iam showing you something similar like you want hope it helps you

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
setInterval('animateImages()', 4000);
})
function animateImages(){
     var $active = $('#fade .active');
     var $next = ($active.next().length > 0) ? $active.next() : $('#fade img:first');
     $next.css('z-index',2);
    $active.fadeOut(1000,function(){
   $active.css('z-index',1).show().removeClass('active');
     $next.css('z-index',3).addClass('active');
      });
    }
```

```css
#fade{position:relative;}
#fade img{position:absolute;z-index:1}
#fade img.active{z-index:3}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="fade">
<img class="active" src="https://prod-filesbucket-7hmmorphht20.s3-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/legacyfiles-smooth/sleepy20face.jpg" alt="My image" />
<img src="http://emojidictionary.emojifoundation.com/img/emoji50.jpg" alt="My image" /> 
</div>
```

**NB: But make sure to have your image same size otherwise fadeout one will overlap the fadein  one